# dropdown list from dictionary mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have this model

```
public class ExistingPlant
{
          public Dictionary<Guid,string> plantList { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateFrom() 
   {
        ExistingPlant existing = new ExistingPlant();

        Dictionary<Guid, string> plants = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();

        foreach(var item in context.Plants){

            plants.Add(item.PlantId , item.ScientificName);
             }

        existing.plantList = plants;

        return View();
    }
```

I need help to create the dropdown list for the dictionary in my view.Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will bind to the form in mvc and pass the model back to the controller on submit with a selectedPlant.

Warning: Some efficiency and best practices [Mostly naming conventions] were ignored in the following code, it's simply based off what you posted.

Model:

```
public class ExistingPlant
{
          public string selectedPlant { get; set; }
          public Dictionary<Guid,string> plantList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateFrom() 
   {
        ExistingPlant existing = new ExistingPlant();

        Dictionary<Guid, string> plants = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();

        foreach(var item in context.Plants){
            plants.Add(item.PlantId , item.ScientificName);
        }

        existing.plantList = plants;

        existing.selectedPlant = "Value"; //Setting preselected value.

        return View(existing); //Pass the model to the view
    }
```

View:

```
  @model ExistingPlant

  @Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.selectedPlant, 
        new SelectList(Model.plantList, "Value", "Key")
    )
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply.It didnt work it made the dropdown list however  which the GUID number not the plants .

Comment: Your dictionary is backwards then. instead of `plants.Add(item.PlantId , item.ScientificName);` use `plants.Add(item.ScientificName, item.PlantId );`

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly after i switched the key and value in the  select list.I have another question , i want for example to create a new plant from an already existing plant , so i have to copy all the fields of this specific plant to a new plant with different name.How can i do it?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. If you have another question, you should post another question with code samples and an explanation of expected behavior and the problem your facing! Someone will be able to help =)

Comment: Hello, i asked the question under the title Create from Existing MVC.Please help